# IdentityServer4 for .NET Framework 4.5 and OAuth 1.0?

Tags: .net-4.5, identityserver4, oauth-1.0a

I would like to know if IdentityServer4 can be used for .NET Framework 4.5 and OAuth 1.0?

Comment: If you want to know the specifications of IdentityServer4, you can find it here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/intro/specs.html

Answer (score 0):

No yo OAuth 1.0 but yes to be able to consume IDS4 from regular old .Net